# Loops in Lean programming language

Tags: loops, lean

I'm starting to learn about `Lean` programming language https://leanprover.github.io

I've found out that there are functions, structures, if/else, and other common programming commands.

However, I haven't found anything to deal with `loops`. Is there a way of iterating or repeating a block of code in Lean? Something similar to `for` or `while` in other languages. If so, please add the syntaxis or an example.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like other functional programming languages, loops in Lean are primarily done via recursion. For example:

```
-- lean 3
def numbers : ℕ → list ℕ
| 0 := []
| (n+1) := n :: numbers n
```

This is a bit of a change of mindset if you aren't used to it. See: [Haskell from C: Where are the for Loops?](https://www.fpcomplete.com/blog/2013/06/haskell-from-c/)

To complicate matters, Lean makes a distinction between *general* recursion and *structural* recursion. The above example is using structural recursion on `ℕ`, so we know that it always halts. Non-halting programs can lead to inconsistency in a DTT-based theorem prover like lean, so it has to be strictly controlled. You can opt in to general recursion using the `meta` keyword:

```
-- lean 3
meta def foo : ℕ → ℕ
| n := if n = 100 then 0 else foo (n + 1) + 1
```

---

In lean 4, the `do` block syntax includes a `for` command, which can be used to write for loops in a more imperative style. Note that they are still represented as tail-recursive functions under the hood, and there are some typeclasses powering the desugaring. (Also you need the `partial` keyword instead of `meta` to do general recursion in lean 4.)

```
-- lean 4
partial def foo (n : Nat) : Nat :=
  if n = 100 then 0 else foo (n + 1) + 1

def mySum (n : Nat) : Nat := Id.run do
  let mut acc := 0
  for i in [0:n] do
    acc := acc + i
  pure acc
```

Comment: Oh I understand now. Thank you very much. I found a Lean example where the keyword "iterate" is used. However, my VM says that it's an unknown identifier. Do you know anything about it?

Comment: Most likely that's the [`nat.iterate`](https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib_docs/find/nat.iterate) function, and your example had `open nat` somewhere up above.

Comment: Here are the docs for `meta`: https://leanprover.github.io/lean4/doc/lean3changes.html?highlight=meta#the-meta-keyword, not so easy to find.